# How to make this slider auto play?

Tags: javascript, slider, playback

I am trying to get this slider to auto play in Javascript (jquery) but I can't seem to get it to work, Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Every time I tried something it seemed to break the slider buttons.

jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/EsdB7/5/

Here is the current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22686964/3917091) is correct, but if you want it to automatically play when the page loads, you can add this to your variable declarations:

```
var auto = setInterval(moveRight, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 sec
```

like so:

```
var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
var auto = setInterval(moveRight, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the following code -

```
var auto = setInterval(moveRight, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 sec
```

after :

```
$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});
 //any where after the declaration of moveRight function.
```

whats happening is that, the moveRight function is being called after every 1000 ms.
[JS FIDDLE of the edited code](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/EsdB7/26/)